# JIRA issues - 1 task per feature or sub-tasks per individual?

Tags: jira

We use Jira for issues bugs estimates and timesheets.

I've seen 2 approaches to using Jira and I want to hear what other people are doing.

**Approach 1:**

Log one feature, such as "Allow user to save as CSV". The task is assigned to a Developer and the workflow progresses from Not started, In Progress, Complete. Once done it's assigned to a Tester and they change workflow to Testing, then to Tested/Completed.

**Approach 2:**

Log a task/user story called "Allow user to save as CSV". Then developer logs subtasks such as, Front end, Backend and tester logs tasks such as create test plan, test right clicking. Once all dev and test sub-tasks are complete, someone marks the task as completed.

I prefer the first way, I've heard the second way is better for tracking time. It seems harder to manage what's going on with a sea of issues in Jira.

Answer (score 1):

My company does first approach. This seems to be working so far ( about a year now ). With either approach I really love how everything seems to be logged in JIRA for history tracking.

Comment: Arthur, we prefer the 2nd approach so all team members (design, dev and QA) can add their estimates. Does your team estimate their work? If you have QA staff, do they estimate their re-testing? I think that's the key reason for the 2nd approach

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using sub-tasks when you need to have work proceed in parallel. Or if the parent task is really large and the sub-tasks are around a few days each. But don't create sub-tasks unless they are needed.

Comment: mdoar, yes, such as a feature needing an api/server side changes and changes to a native app. this approach only considers development though. Does your team log QA sub-tasks for your testers?